# Add Microstructure Tag

Tags: feature-request

I was not able to find a 'microstructure' tag that I believe could be used on my post.

Can this be created?  Or give reasons why its a bad idea.

(I do not have the rep to create it, otherwise I would have)

Answer (score 6):

A tag becomes useful when there are at least several questions that could use that tag. Therefore related questions for that topic can be easily found. Currently a search of this SE site only show one answer where the word is used.

Ask the question and if it is a good question and on topic, and it results in several more questions then there will be a need for a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how that tag really would relate to personal finance. Seems more like an economics term, which is off topic on the site.

Comment: I see nothing in help banning questions on how markets work.  This is not economics related microstructure.

Comment: I don't see any value in creating such a tag.

Comment: @BAR Tags are for questions, and questions here ought to relate to practical personal finance. Questions on "how markets work" *may* be considered related to personal finance, or they may not. One would have to see the particular question to judge whether it fits the personal finance criteria. "Microstructure" seems like a term one would come across more on the theoretical side of finance, and somebody *asking* a question about microstructure (as opposed to referencing the idea in an answer) may be asking in the wrong place.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea There are too many examples to list concisely, but microstructure can relate to personal finance, where questions on 'how markets work' do as well.

Comment: @BAR And when we have enough such real questions that do survive the on-topic test, then it may be warranted. i.e. what mhoran_psprep said in his answer.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Unfortunately I do not have the time to see if more posts could take use of this.  Just thought it applies and had more usage.  I haven't seen too many outside the industry use the term properly, so its likely there are posts where it applies but the poster did not realize.